# Can we show that $h(t)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \min \{ f(x), f(x+t) \} dx$ is decreasing function for $t \ge 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We are interested in the following function:

\begin{align}
h(t)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \min \{ f(x), f(x+t) \} dx
\end{align}
is decreasing function for $t \ge 0$ where $f$ is non-negative and integrable.

Can we show that $h(t)$ is a non-increasing function of $t$? If not, what would be an example of $f$ that makes it non-increasing?

Comment: In the last sentence, did you mean "what would be an example of $f$ that makes it not non-increasing?" (what you've written has the answers of "no" and $f=0$, but I doubt that's what you actually meant)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks. I have correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$f(x) = \frac{\max(0, \sin(x))}{1+x^2}$$

Then $h(0), h(2\pi) > 0$ but $h(\pi) = 0$

Comment: @ thanks. Do you think there is a simpler example where we can actually calculate $h(t)$ for all $t$?